# Wordpress Redirects on Install

Tags: loop, admin, installation

I'm having problems when trying to install wordpress on subdomain.

I've downloaded the arhive from wordpress.org, unzip it on root folder and when trying to install it says 
[image]

I found and tryed several solutions like

- creating a htaccess file
- clearing cookies
- checking/repairing database (even if no table created)
- correct file permission

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try the same zip on localhost or some other hosting?.  And also try the `tar.gz` file as well. If it gives the same redirect loop update your question again

Comment: What is in the `.htaccess` file? Sounds like a server configuration issue to me, though. You will have to provide more information about your setup.

Comment: i tried also with the latest.tar.gz arhive. but samt problem. On localhost work fine :)

@s_ha_dum i had to manually create the file and was took from another wp installation with same config. basic config from https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Also i have other wordpress sites running on other subdomains. Those, however were migrated there. Please tell what other setup info i may provide

Comment: How did you configure your subdomain, for example?

Comment: well, via cpanel :)

Comment: and on localhost work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was created by some code in the htaccess from root.

So:
To present exactly my configuration:

I have 
 - http://maindomain.org with file directly in the root of my hosting. I know this may not be a best practice and i'll change this.

Subdomain i was trying to set was in a folder which was along site my maindomain files.

- wp-admin/
- wp-includes/
- wp-content/
- s/
- .htaccess

On the main site i had install a securrity plugin from ithemes security which was somehow restricting me to install wordpress on a subdomain

The solution i chose was to backup and temporarily remove .htaccess from the root to install my wordpress.

Next step is to move my main site on a subfolder to prevent future problems like this.

I leave this here in hope others how get this error to find it. In case my response is messy don't hessitate to suggest and edit or to contact me.

Thanks stackexchange